# Retrieving records that have a unique field using Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have an ActiveRecord User model that has a telephone field. Some users have the same telephone. I want a list of users who have a unique telephone number. If more than one user has the same telephone number I do not care which one is chosen. In the rails console, I can do

```
User.unscoped.group(:telephone).count
```

which gives me the number of times each telephone number occurs, so `User.group(:telepone)` seems a good place to start (I need to do the unscoped because there is a default scope defined on the model).  However if I type

```
User.unscoped.group(:telephone).first
```

I get an exception:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" GROUP BY "users"."name" ORDER...
                ^
: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" GROUP BY "users"."name" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1
/Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7@golf_mentor/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:677:in `async_prepare'
```

How do I use the `User.unscoped.group(:name` to achieve what I want.

Comment: Check all user records for telephone_id is exist or not. The logic which you written absolutely fine. You need to check association there or not between user and telephone and telephone_id having values or not in users table.

Comment: @kishore, I tried ```User.where.not(telephone: nil).group(:telephone).first``` but it still raised an exception. In any case, I am satisfied with @pawel's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want a list of users who have a unique telephone number

You can get this list by calling `User.unscoped.select("DISTINCT ON (telephone) *").order("telephone DESC")`

The order part is needed otherwise you will experience this error:

```
Caused by PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
```

**Update:**

As mentioned in the comments, with Rails 6 and PostgreSQL 11.3 `order` part is no longer needed.

Comment: Prefix `users.` isn't needed, as you're only using the `users` table. For Rails 6, PostgreSQL 11.3 order isn't needed either.